# emlrt.h file in c language wasn't found

Tags: c, matlab

We converted the MATLAB files to the C language, and ran the files in Visual-Studio.

We have inserted all the required classes except the class: "emlrt.h". We were unable to insert and cause the project to compile properly.

If someone knows of a version of the "emlrt.h" class that works on files that have been converted from Matlab, we will be happy to see it.

Comment: Have you tried any of the offerings revealed by [https://www.google.com/search?q=emlrt.h](https://www.google.com/search?q=emlrt.h)?

Comment: It is just an interface for exporting that you probably don't need.